# Writing Javascript for inverse proportion

Tags: javascript, math

Having a bit of time trying to write some javascript to make this inverse proportion work. Basically an element will have a point value based on its size.

```
| size | points |
|------|--------|
| 10   | 10     |
| 20   | 9      |
| 30   | 8      |
| 40   | 7      |
| 50   | 6      |
| 60   | 5      |
| 70   | 4      |
| 80   | 3      |
| 90   | 2      |
| 100  | 1      |
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: 11 - (size / 10)

Answer (score 4):

You could take the delta of 11 and the tenth of the number.

```js
function fn(n) {
    return 11 - n / 10;
}

var i;

for (i = 10; i <= 100; i += 10) {
    console.log(i, fn(i));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is great, one question. How do you determine the delta? Could this be done programmatically? Or do we assume 11 because we know the step is 10?